# $push and $sum with the aggregation framework on sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a data as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d4410544c96d6f6578f893"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteName": "Suite1",
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS",
        },
        {
            "suiteName": "Suite2",
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL",
        },
        {
            "suiteName": "Suite3",
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS",
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:40:47.049Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d4410544c96d6f6578f894"),
    "executionProject" : "Project1",
    "suiteList" : [ 
        {
            "suiteName": "Suite1",
            "suiteStatus" : "PASS",
        },
        {
            "suiteName": "Suite2",
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL",
        },
        {
            "suiteName": "Suite3",
            "suiteStatus" : "FAIL",
        }
    ],
    "runEndTime" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:50:47.049Z")
}
```

And I was trying to get the result like this:

```
{
    "executionProject": "Project1",
    "data": [
        {
            "date": "2015-08-19 08:40:47",
            "suitePass": 2,
            "suiteFail": 1
        },
        {
            "date": "2015-08-19 08:50:47",
            "suitePass": 1,
            "suiteFail": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I'm trying to group by `executionProject` and push the `runEndTime` and the pass and fail counts of `suites` to the result.

I tried this, but giving me wrong way of projection:

```
db.testruns.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            executionProject: "$executionProject",
            runEndTime: "$runEndTime",
            suiteList: "$suiteList"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$suiteList"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$executionProject",
            runEndTime: {
                $addToSet: "$runEndTime"
            },
            suite_pass: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        "if": {
                            $eq: ["$suiteList.suiteStatus", "PASS"]
                        },
                        "then": 1,
                        "else": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            runEndTime: { $push: {runTime: "$runEndTime", suite_pass: "$suite_pass"} }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            executionProject: "$_id",
            runEndTime: "$runEndTime",
            _id: 0
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to group by the document to get the suite totals, then you add to the array as you group on the project. Also don't forget to "sort" if you want things in order:

```js
  [
      { "$unwind": "$suiteList" },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "executionProject": { "$first": "$executionProject" },
        "suite-pass": { 
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$suiteList.suiteStatus", "PASS" ] },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "suite-fail": { 
          "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
              { "$eq": [ "$suiteList.suiteStatus", "FAIL" ] },
              1,
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        "date": { "$first": "$runEndTime" }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "executionProject": 1, "date": 1 } },
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$executionProject",
        "data": {
          "$push": { 
            "suite-pass": "$suite-pass",
            "suite-fail": "$suite-fail",
            "date": "$date"
          }
        }
      }}
  ]
```

Produces:

```js
{
    "_id" : "Project1",
    "data" : [
            {
                    "suite-pass" : 2,
                    "suite-fail" : 1,
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:40:47.049Z")
            },
            {
                    "suite-pass" : 1,
                    "suite-fail" : 2,
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-08-19T08:50:47.049Z")
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Blakes, you are a saviour man. I would like to learn more from you. Why don't you write a blog or some article on advanced aggregation?